# How to plot a label under block if in tradingview

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm doing a backtest in tradingview and I waould like to export the data for more detail.
However, I could not see the label with the exported data.

How do I plot the label and show it in the exported data?

I've put plot(lastConfirmedPivotBar) to try to plot the label, but it comes out with an error:

Cannot use 'plot' in local scope

```
//@version=5
indicator('Historical Pattern Matcher', 'Pattern matcher', overlay=true, max_labels_count=500)

useAlternativeSource = input.bool(false, title='Use Alternative Source', group='Zigzag', inline='src')
source = input.source(close, title='', group='Zigzag', inline='src')
zigzagLength = input.int(11, step=1, minval=3, title='Length', group='Zigzag', inline='main')
i_loopback = input.int(12, step=10, title='Lookback Pivots', group='Pattern Recognition Settings')

max_array_size = i_loopback * 3

var zigzagpivots = array.new_float(0)
var zigzagpivotbars = array.new_int(0)
var zigzagpivotdirs = array.new_int(0)

f_color_hsl(_hue, _saturation, _lightness, _transparency) =>  //{

    float _l1 = _lightness / 100.0
    float _a = _saturation * math.min(_l1, 1.0 - _l1) / 100.0
    float _rk = (0.0 + _hue / 30.0) % 12.0
    float _r = 255.0 * (_l1 - _a * math.max(math.min(_rk - 3.0, 9.0 - _rk, 1.0), -1.0))
    float _gk = (8.0 + _hue / 30.0) % 12.0
    float _g = 255.0 * (_l1 - _a * math.max(math.min(_gk - 3.0, 9.0 - _gk, 1.0), -1.0))
    float _bk = (4.0 + _hue / 30.0) % 12.0
    float _b = 255.0 * (_l1 - _a * math.max(math.min(_bk - 3.0, 9.0 - _bk, 1.0), -1.0))
    color.rgb(_r, _g, _b, _transparency)

f_random_color(transparency) =>
    f_color_hsl(math.random(0, 255), math.random(70, 100), math.random(30, 70), transparency)

add_to_array(arr, val, maxItems) =>
    array.unshift(arr, val)
    if array.size(arr) > maxItems
        array.pop(arr)

pivots(length) =>
    highsource = useAlternativeSource ? source : high
    lowsource = useAlternativeSource ? source : low
    float phigh = ta.highestbars(highsource, length) == 0 ? highsource : na
    float plow = ta.lowestbars(lowsource, length) == 0 ? lowsource : na
    [phigh, plow, bar_index, bar_index]

addnewpivot(zigzagpivots, zigzagpivotbars, zigzagpivotdirs, value, bar, dir) =>
    newDir = dir
    if array.size(zigzagpivots) >= 2
        LastPoint = array.get(zigzagpivots, 1)
        newDir := dir * value > dir * LastPoint ? dir * 2 : dir
        newDir
    add_to_array(zigzagpivots, value, max_array_size)
    add_to_array(zigzagpivotbars, bar, max_array_size)
    add_to_array(zigzagpivotdirs, newDir, max_array_size)

zigzagcore(phigh, plow, phighbar, plowbar, zigzagpivots, zigzagpivotbars, zigzagpivotdirs) =>
    pDir = 1
    newZG = false
    doubleZG = phigh and plow
    if array.size(zigzagpivots) >= 1
        pDir := array.get(zigzagpivotdirs, 0)
        pDir := pDir % 2 == 0 ? pDir / 2 : pDir
        pDir

    if (pDir == 1 and phigh or pDir == -1 and plow) and array.size(zigzagpivots) >= 1
        pivot = array.shift(zigzagpivots)
        pivotbar = array.shift(zigzagpivotbars)
        pivotdir = array.shift(zigzagpivotdirs)
        value = pDir == 1 ? phigh : plow
        bar = pDir == 1 ? phighbar : plowbar

        useNewValues = value * pivotdir > pivot * pivotdir
        value := useNewValues ? value : pivot
        bar := useNewValues ? bar : pivotbar
        newZG := newZG or useNewValues
        addnewpivot(zigzagpivots, zigzagpivotbars, zigzagpivotdirs, value, bar, pDir)

    if pDir == 1 and plow or pDir == -1 and phigh
        value = pDir == 1 ? plow : phigh
        bar = pDir == 1 ? plowbar : phighbar
        dir = pDir == 1 ? -1 : 1
        newZG := true
        addnewpivot(zigzagpivots, zigzagpivotbars, zigzagpivotdirs, value, bar, dir)

    [newZG, doubleZG]

zigzag(length, zigzagpivots, zigzagpivotbars, zigzagpivotdirs) =>
    [phigh, plow, phighbar, plowbar] = pivots(length)
    zigzagcore(phigh, plow, phighbar, plowbar, zigzagpivots, zigzagpivotbars, zigzagpivotdirs)

[level1ZG, doublel1ZG] = zigzag(zigzagLength, zigzagpivots, zigzagpivotbars, zigzagpivotdirs)

var patternArray = array.new_string(0)
var patternBarArray = array.new_int(0)
pattern = ''

lastIndex = 0
if array.size(zigzagpivots) > i_loopback * 2 + 2
    lastConfirmedPivot = array.get(zigzagpivots, 1)
    lastConfirmedPivotBar = array.get(zigzagpivotbars, 1)
    lastConfirmedPivotDir = array.get(zigzagpivotdirs, 1)
    if ta.change(lastConfirmedPivot)
        for i = 1 to i_loopback - 1 by 1
            iDir = array.get(zigzagpivotdirs, i) % 2
            iDir := iDir % 2 == 0 ? iDir / 2 : iDir
            for j = i + 2 to i_loopback + 1 by 2
                iPivotPattern = iDir * array.get(zigzagpivots, i) > iDir * array.get(zigzagpivots, j) ? iDir * 2 : iDir
                pattern := pattern + str.tostring(iDir)
                pattern
        lastIndex := array.indexof(patternArray, pattern)
        if lastIndex != -1
            randomColor = f_random_color(70)
            lastBarIndex = array.get(patternBarArray, lastIndex)
            lastOccurance = time[bar_index - lastBarIndex]

            lastTime = str.tostring(year(lastOccurance), '0000') + '/' + str.tostring(month(lastOccurance), '00') + '/' + str.tostring(dayofmonth(lastOccurance), '00') + (timeframe.isintraday ? '-' + str.tostring(hour(lastOccurance), '00') + ':' + str.tostring(minute(lastOccurance), '00') + ':' + str.tostring(second(lastOccurance), '00') : '')
            yloc = lastConfirmedPivotDir > 0 ? yloc.abovebar : yloc.belowbar
            style = lastConfirmedPivotDir > 0 ? label.style_triangledown : label.style_triangleup
            label.new(lastConfirmedPivotBar, close, text='', color=randomColor, style=style, tooltip='⬅ ' + lastTime, yloc=yloc)
        array.unshift(patternArray, pattern)
        array.unshift(patternBarArray, bar_index)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the plot function inside an if block.
To work around this issue:

1. Declare a special variable to hold the index value in the global scope before your if block, at the same level as the `patternArray` and `patternBarArray` variables.
2. Right after the `label.new()` function that draws the label, change the value of your variable to `lastConfirmedPivotBar`
3. At the end of the script, in the global scope (outside the if blocks), call the `plot()` function, specifying your custom variable as the series.

Pseudo example:

```
// your code
...
// line 89-92 ->
int pivot = na // Initialize variable for store label index 
var patternArray = array.new_string(0)
var patternBarArray = array.new_int(0)
pattern = ''
...
if array.size(zigzagpivots) > i_loopback * 2 + 2
    ...
        label.new(lastConfirmedPivotBar, close, text='', color=randomColor, style=style, tooltip='⬅ ' + lastTime, yloc=yloc)
        pivot := lastConfirmedPivotBar // set the label index to the variable
    array.unshift(patternArray, pattern)
    array.unshift(patternBarArray, bar_index)

// plot variable in the global scope (line 121)
plot(pivot, style = plot.style_circles)
```

I hope you understand the code you have and will be able to understand the reduced pseudo-example.

Keep in mind that the value of the bar index on your current chart will be displayed in the plot, these values may differ when reloading the chart if the number of available bars changes (due to the subscription level or the unavailability of earlier data).
To avoid this, you can output the relative offset from the current bar to always get the same result for the same labels:

```
plot(bar_index - pivot, style = plot.style_circles)
```